# Разъединить склеенный файл

Tags: bat, mp4

Склеил файлы MP4 через batch
copy /b file1.mp4 + file2.mp4 + file3.mp4 + file4.mp4 clip.mp4
Но видеофайл clip.mp4 воспроизводится как file4.mp4(размер тот же)
Что делать если исходные файлы удалены ?

Comment: Просто - никак. Сложно - изучить формат MP4, определить длину каждого файла, выгрузить каждый в отдельный файл.

Comment: В принципе у MP4 вполне себе вменяемый заголовок, который легко ищется бинарным поиском. Найти все 4 (впрочем, где будет первый - и так понятно) да поделить по ним.

Comment: Если предполагается, что заголовки файлов "битые" - затруднительно их найти - то можно в старых копиях MFT (если речь идёт об  NTFS) найти сведения о размере удаленных файлов. А дальше, просто поделить результирующий файл на соответствующие размерам части. Для поиска удаленных файлов существует множество платных и бесплатных утилит.